# How to isolate development sessions from production sessions in Crashlytics (Android)

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Hi recently published a Crashlytics enabled mobile app and we don't how to make it so that our development sessions do not skew the result of the daily reports we get from the service.

Ideally we'd want to have separate reports for development sessions and productions service but without having to resort to complicated adjustments like changing the package name.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Crashlytics here.

In addition to changing the name of your app which was mentioned, you can also create multiple organizations and conditionally call which API key to use based on the type of build you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the version name to Beta in your manifest